# VS2010 docks code windows in the wrong place

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2017

When I double click on an entry in my Error List or Find Results list in VS2010, it docks the newly opened source code file not in the large window where all my other source files go, but in the small narrow window at the bottom along with the error list etc.

How can I get it to put it up with the others by default?

If I double-click an item in Solution explorer it puts it in the right place

Comment: This isn't really a programming question, but would be suitable on superuser.

Comment: If you double-click to open it in the wrong place, then move it to the preferred/correct place, then close and reopen VS2010, does it save your window settings? (It works that way on older versions.)

Comment: @ewall thanks for the suggestion, but it didn't help

Answer (score 149, accepted):

I got things back to normal by using the **Window | Reset Window Layout** menu option. I noticed that now the tabs for "Error List" "Output" "Pending Changes" etc were now at the bottom of their docked window rather than the top. I think I somehow or other must have created a second code window area and docked my error list window etc into that.

Incorrectly docked (tabs at the top):

[image: VS2010 Output window incorrectly docked]

Correctly docked (tabs at the bottom):

[image: VS2010 Output window correctly docked]

Comment: Excellent. Glad you found the fix!

Comment: I was hesitant to Reset 'all' my settings, as others mention, but Studio did exactly what I wanted! It restored my rather complex setup, which possibly had been saved.

Comment: I just want to say how much this was driving me insane, and how much I want to thank you for this fix.

Comment: So Reset Window Layout did not work for me. Re-positioning the windows so that the tabs were on the bottom was the fix. Thanks for the info.

Comment: 2015 this does not work at all. So excellent suggestion. but no solution for me. Target window always opens in current tab group as opposed to the main editor tab group.

Answer (score 45):

I too had this problem and now **found the cause**: if you move the bottom window pane a visual guide is shown on which you can **dock them to various places**. For the bottom two visual options are shown - one where the pane will be part of the upper pane and one were it will be placed below the upper pane. The second choice gives a proper behavior wereas the first one gives you the tab titles at the top and doesn't work.

I think this is very annoying because it happens from time to time that I **accidentally drag** the pane. (I'm using a tablet) Probably this dragging is the cause for the trouble.

Comment: I discovered this on my own. This was much preferably to resetting all of my settings.

Comment: Thanks. I had this in VS 2012 and resetting the layout options did not work. Moving the lower panes to the correct place did work though.

Answer (score 8):

I was having the same issue but, for a number of reasons, didnt want to reset all my settings.

I draged all the open windows from the bottom panel area so they were floating, closed the find results window, redocked the error and output windows, then did a search (find in files) and the new floating window popped up, I then docked this to the same area that errors and output were in and when I double clicked on a file in the results window it opened in the right place.

I hope this works for you to and anyone else experiencing this issue...

Comment: Yes, re-docking the output/find/etc in the proper place resolved my issues as well. 
I must have farkled the layout somehow ...

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't find the Window -> Reset Window Layout option.  The above answers helped me understand, the problem was with me having moved around my windows.  What finally helped me was the little symbols on the top right corner of the find results window.  Instead of the usual 'Inverted triangle'+'Pushpin'+'x' symbols, what I saw was just the Inverted Triangle, which meant I docked the find results window in the main file docking area.  So, when I moved it to the bottom docking area in Visual studio, it worked for me.

Comment: Your finding helped me.  It seems that if the find results window is docked, then double click will open the file in the same panel.  If the find results window is floating, the file will open in the desired location.