# Visual Studio Clicking Find Results Opens Code in Wrong Window

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, find, replace

I'm using Visual Studio 2010 and when I do a "Find in Files" the results are returned to the "Find Results 1" window which is docked below my code editor window.

Before, I would double click on one of the results in the Find Results window and the file I clicked on would open in the code editor panel.

The problem is now when I click on one of the results, it opens in the same panel as the Find Results window which happens to be much smaller than the code editor window which is annoying.

Does anyone know how to make it so that when I double click on the search results they open up in the code editor window again?

Thanks!

Comment: I tried to add `visual-studio-2013` tag but it wouldn't let me, but this still happens in 2013!! even with reset window

Comment: possible duplicate of [VS2010 docks code windows in the wrong place](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2730925/vs2010-docks-code-windows-in-the-wrong-place)

Answer (score 352):

Click *Window → Reset Window Layout*

Comment: The same command (`Window -> Reset Window Layout`) exists in Visual Studio 2013 and continues to solve the problem ;).

Comment: Thanks. Works in VS2015 also

Comment: This solution usually fixes it for me quickly. However, one instance, it didn't work first time but worked after restarting VS.

Comment: Works in VS2017 as well

Comment: Also successful in VS2019

Comment: When I reset to the default window layout and attempt to open Test Explorer, it opens as a floating popup. If I manually move it to the bottom, then new windows will open in the tiny part at the bottom again.

Comment: Also successful in VS2022

Answer (score 149):

**Works for VS2013 Update 4 and all newer versions, including VS2019.**

I thought I had this problem but it was easily fixed by docking the Find Results window using the very bottom of the window position selectors.

The files open in the same position as the Find Results when the window is docked in the positions immediately next to the centre position.

[image: VS2013 window position selector]

Comment: this helped. Resetting the window layout didn't help im my case

Comment: Works in Visual Studio 2015 as well

Comment: Works in Visual Studio 2017 too

Comment: Far better solution then the did-you-try-to-restart-your-computer accepted solution

Comment: Worked for me and then I redocked the Solution Explorer and Properties window to the side in the way that I prefer. Code files still open in the main pane after doing this extra step.

Comment: Underrated answer because of the Image shown. The difference for example on the right side are the two dock options. In case you docked your Find Results into a split-view, it will open files on top of itself and act as source panel. If you dock it to the outer more slim single-view like >[] it will act like a side-bar and open files in the another existing source panel. Same for the other options, while default is bottom-sidebar style.

Comment: Works in Visual Studio 2019 too :)

Answer (score 13):

This is also being discussed here:
   [VS2010 docks code windows in the wrong place](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2730925/vs2010-docks-code-windows-in-the-wrong-place)

Answer (score 4):

Go the same... irritating... I realized that this unwanted behavior happened only while the app was running in debug.  After I stopped debugging, a new panel was created with this file open in it.  If I opened new files, they would open in this new panel.  If I close all files in this new panel, opening new files from the "Find In Files" open in the standard code editor window (as long as the app is not running).

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem also.  I experienced the problem in VS2013.  I did not want to do "Window -> Reset Window Layout" because it seemed like that was going to do other stuff that I did not want it to do.

Here was my solution:

1. I noticed the problem in VS2013 in which I had project "A" open.
2. I opened another copy of VS2013 and opened project "B".
3. I closed the copy of VS2013 that was exhibiting the annoying behavior: project A.
4. I closed the copy of VS2013 that had project B open.
5. This saved the settings from the "good" copy.
6. Opened project A in VS2013 and all was well.

Obviously, the caveat is that this requires you notice the problem before you close VS2013.  But if you do notice it in time, this is a pretty easy solution.

Answer (score 3):

For those who do not want to dock their "Find Results", "Error List", "Output",... windows to the right, and for those the above answer which is Window->Reset Window Layout doesn't work: may be you are trying to dock wrong place! You should dock these windows to very bottom. Refer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2735726/6176317

Answer (score 0):

For me, this was happening with a Visual Studio window containing an SQL file with the Window Split option active.  If the cursor was in the top pane of the window, both Ctrl + F (Find) and Ctrl + H (Find & Replace) would cause the find control to appear in the other (main) Visual Studio window.  Moving the SQL window into the main window just caused Find and Find & Replace to display the "Find in Files" dialog instead until another tab was selected.

The workaround was to place the cursor in the bottom pane which caused both Find and Find & Replace to work correctly in that pane of that window.  Unfortunately as long as the Window Split is there, the bug is still there in the top pane.